# How to rewrite pplEditor in Sharepoint to something that can be used in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I would like to write a tool which can search through users in the active directory. At the moment, I am working on a pre-existing code that uses Sharepoint 2007. I would like to convert that from Sharepoint 2007 to ASP.NET. Within this pre-existing code is a reference to pplEditor of sharepoint, which I am assuming is being used to look through the active directory. I want to rewrite this code so I am not referencing pplEditor at all. Rather I would like an 'alternative' that can access the users in the active directory. Code is in C#.

List(string)_lstExistingLogin = null;

```
        Label lblLoginID;

        if (pplEditor.ResolvedEntities.Count > 0)
        {
            if (gvAssignedTos.Rows.Count > 0){
            // if the hospital already has existing data coordinators associated with it, 
          // build a list of this set of existing datacoordinators
                _lstExistingLogin = new List<string>();
                foreach (GridViewRow row in gvAssignedTos.Rows)
                {
                    lblLoginID = (Label)row.FindControl("lblLoginID");

                    if (lblLoginID.Text.Length > 0)
                    {
                        _lstExistingLogin.Add(lblLoginID.Text);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

[ALL Operations on Active Directory (AD) using c#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/all-operations-on-active-directory-ad-using-C-Sharp/) by using System.DirectoryServices.

Not sure whether you're inheriting from pplEditor, while it can be used in SharePoint.

[People picker control implementation in asp.net mvc application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701488/people-picker-control-implementation-in-asp-net-mvc-application)